# How to split lines based on the cursor position?

Tags: java, string, parsing, csv, tokenize

I have a text file which has all the information I need in lines and this needs to be converted into a .csv file.

Example:

```
abbccccdeffffiiiiiiiiiiiiiijjkkkkkkkkkkkllmmmmmmnnooo
abbccccdeffffiiiiiiiiiiiiiijjkkkkkkkkkkkllmmmmmmnnooo
abbccccdeffffiiiiiiiiiiiiiijjkkkkkkkkkkkllmmmmmmnnooo
abbccccdeffffiiiiiiiiiiiiiijjkkkkkkkkkkkllmmmmmmnnooo
abbccccdeffffiiiiiiiiiiiiiijjkkkkkkkkkkkllmmmmmmnnooo
abbccccdeffffiiiiiiiiiiiiiijjkkkkkkkkkkkllmmmmmmnnooo
```

So basically

- 1."a" is first column with just one char
- 2."bb" is second column with length 2
- 3."cccc" is third column with length 4
- 4."d" is fourth column with length 1
- 5."e" is fifth column with length 1
- 6."ffff" is sixth column with length 4

As we can see from this example, I cannot use a delimiter with space or commas, they are all of different lengths. Please point me to the right direction. I just need an idea of how to approach to this problem.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: If all lines follow the pattern you just need to read each line, substring it `String.substring( [start], [amount] )` then reconcatenate with the `;` which will be readable as csv

Comment: @JorgeCampos You meant `,`, right?

Comment: @Andreas Well after you mentioned it, I went to check it on my excel and it turns out that we both are right. Default csv use `,` but if you chose `ms-dos .csv` it uses `;` I guess that I was used to the old clipper programming :P

Comment: @JorgeCampos Well, I was primarily thinking of the `c` in `csv`, you know "[**Comma**-Separated-Values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)".

Comment: Please check the answer below. I have given a fair idea about how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You are aware of the `length` of value for each column, you can use the `substring` method of String.

```
string.substring(start, start+length);
```

where `start` is the start index for a column and `length` is the length of the colume value.

Use `StringBuilder` for converting them into `csv` format. AS you calculate the column value, keep on appending them into the `stringBuilder` object along with a `,`. Once the last column is retrieved and appended then using `toString()` convert it to `String` and write to the stream of your choice.

I would suggest you, to use the same `StringBuilder` object instead of creating a new one for each row. Just reset the size to zero (`StringBuilder.size(0)`), once you write it the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `indexOf`, `lastIndexOf` and `substring` method from String? Then you can find the places where you can put your delimiter.

```
String myString = "abbcccdee";

int lastCharIndex = 0;
while (true) {
    if(lastCharIndex == myString.length()){
        break;
    }
    //find char
    char nextChar = myString.charAt(lastCharIndex);
    //calculate first char position
    int firstCharIndex = myString.indexOf(nextChar);
    //calculate last char position
    lastCharIndex = myString.lastIndexOf(nextChar) + 1;
    //get value
    String value = myString.substring(firstCharIndex, lastCharIndex);
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- So is the string of fixed length or variable length?
- If you want the java application to be more generic or reusable, you
  can use xml/xsd to define the template, something like

```html
<fileMessage class="MessageParser">
<field name="column1" type="java.lang.String" length="1" variable="id"/>
<field name="column2" type="java.lang.Integer" length="2" variable="age"/>
<field name="column3" type="java.lang.Long" length="4" variable="name"/>
<field name="column4" type="java.lang.String" length="1" variable="gender"/>
</fileMessage>
```

- Write a transformer method which would read the line and map the
  fields to corresponding variables in the MessageParser object.

Once every line is moved to object, play it the way you want.

This is believe involves a bit more effort, and should be used only if you have varying files with different column/row lengths.
else the substring logic would do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use [univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) `FixedWidthParser` and `FixedWidthWriter`.

Here's an example:

```
// creates the sequence of field lengths you need
FixedWidthFieldLengths lengths = new FixedWidthFieldLengths(1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 4);

// creates the default settings for a fixed width parser
FixedWidthParserSettings settings = new FixedWidthParserSettings(lengths);

// creates a fixed-width parser with the given settings
FixedWidthParser parser = new FixedWidthParser(settings);

// parses all rows in one go.
List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(new FileReader(new File("/path/to/file.txt")));
```

To write this to CSV, use a `CsvWriter`:

```
CsvWriterSettings writerSettings = new CsvWriterSettings(); //many options here, check the tutorial
CsvWriter writer = new CsvWriter(new FileWriter(new File("/path/to/file.csv")), writerSettings);

// Writes the headers of the CSV file (not mandatory)
writer.writeHeaders("a", "bb", "cccc", "d", "e", "ffff");

// Here we just tell the writer to write everything and close the given output Writer instance.
writer.writeStringRowsAndClose(allRows); //this method is available in version 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT. If you use version 1.5.6 you must convert the rows to Object[]
```

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).